# What is the difference between Eclipse and Netbeans if I want to use only the Java in it?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, vista64

I recently got a Dell XPS 64-bit Vista for myself. Eclipse doesn't have their 64-bit version, but I've read on forums that they download Eclipse and work with Java 1.5 on the Vista with only some problems. I have Java 1.6 and Netbeans was easily downloadable.

What's the basic/big difference that I'll notice if I shift to Netbeans from Eclipse now?

Comment: i use netbeans on mac for more than 3 years. But today i update to Netbeans v7.3. The UI or messed up + no fullscreen button. I think about stop using netbeans and more focused on eclipse now.

Answer (score 44):

What is the difference between Coke and Pepsi?

Ok, it's not really that similar, but a lot of the differences are in qualitative ways. Speaking of Netbeans 6.1 and 6.5:

- Netbeans has a very different UI and
  workflow. There are no perspectives,
  but toolbars and such will auto
  appear/hide as needed (i.e.
  debugging). Build process is
  different. Managing projects is
  different.
- Netbeans focuses on a smooth,
  integrated experience sometimes at
  the expense of features. The
  Profiler is fully integrated into
  the editor (context menu's let you
  quickly manipulate the profiler),
  but is lacking some featuers of
  Eclipse profilers.
- Netbeans has a tightly integrated
  JSP/Servlet/JSF development
  environment. The whole workflow
  connects together from development,
  debugging, deployment. This is more
  of a "feel" than anything else.
- Netbeans editor is missing several
  Eclipse features. Spell check being
  one prominent one. Quick complete
  (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-J) is an underused
  Netbeans feature. Snippets being
  another (though they have an
  auto-complete template which fills a
  different, but similar niche).
- Less choice. If you don't like one
  of the included tools, it's unlikely
  you will find a good alternative
  plug-in.
- Matisse. Eclipse GUI editors have
  started to catch up, but they are
  simply no comparison to Matisse.
  Superficially, they seem
  equivalent...
- `<sarcasm>`Your friends will make
  fun of you.`</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 8):

Maybe when you work with several (many) projects at the same time I would prefer Eclipse (Workspace organization is great for that). Interface seems to respond better (at least vs old versions of NetBeans such as 5.0) in Eclipse too. This is related to SWT vs Swing performance issues, though the differences are no so big as on Java 1.4 days.

However I would say Netbeans is a better integrated IDE, you launch/debug applications the same way no matter you are developing a desktop application or a JSP/Servlet web application. Building relies entirely (since version 4 I think) on Ant, and Netbeans launches/adds ant target transparently. Ant in Eclipse has the same level of integration as a pair of bull horns sticked to the front of your car.

Eclipse is more extensible than Netbeans but the last is more uniform.

Comment: Netbeans now have Project Groups which is similar to Workgroups. If you need completely different environments, you can launch Netbeans and point at a new ".netbeans" directory.

Comment: Eclipse is not more extensible. The underlying platforms are *roughly* equivalent in capabilities. It's more accurate to say there are far more IDE Plug-Ins for Eclipse than Netbeans.

Answer (score 6):

I think it will be mostly culture shock. Things in different places. Features named different things.

If you really want to give Netbeans a try force yourself to use it for a month. It will suck for the first day or so as none of the shortcuts will be the same, various idioms will be different etc.

At the end of the month you will be competent enough in it that these things should have gone away and you can objectively decide if you like it more. (I'm currently trying this with IntelliJ btw. Current state, confused ;-)

Comment: Really?  I was converted the moment I tried NetBeans.  I like how, by default, they use Ant for building (instead of Eclipses weird custom system).

Answer (score 6):

Why not use both ?

I like netbeans Profiling tools *much* better than eclipse's as they work straight out of the box on Linux.

Eclipse I use for normal editing, the mylin tools really help you work in a task oriented way.

Netbeans supports the import of eclipse projects so you can go along with both IDE's working on a single project if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

Sad to say, you also quickly discover that Netbeans is far more unstable than Eclipse. I give a serious try (more than one month ;)) to 6.1 and that was the more noticeable "feature" for me.  Sometimes, a simple mouvement of the mouse is enough to kill the application.
They made huge progress since 5.x, but imho, Netbeans is still far behind Eclipse.

Comment: I've never experienced the instability you speak of and I've been using NetBeans on a daily basis since version 6.  In fact, if anything, I found Eclipse to be unstable and had the project files routinely corrupt for no reason (forcing me to remake the project).

Comment: Neither have I. I've used Netbeans 5.x (very little) and 6.x a lot.

Comment: agree, i feel netbeans more unstable than eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

The basic workflow of Netbeans is much smoother and more reliable; little things like ^X to cut current line work properly. It's also simple enough to understand what it's doing.

otoh, Eclipse has the emacs quality of being a platform in its own right; some people swear by that.

Edit: I've changed my mind, on coming across HyperAssist: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159157

Quite simply, the HyperAssist plugin fills in the missing piece that kept Eclipse from the gold medal; with it, Eclipse is the best IDE I've ever used.

Answer (score 2):

I've been recently trying Netbeans 6.5 and have found/understand:

- Netbeans has better new language support (as it is the "reference" IDE/implementation for new technologies)
- Similar to above, but Eclipse *still* doesn't have 1-1 generic compatibility with sun's javac or an option to "make it compatible" (Eclipse is too smart about inferring types - correct, but no good if your build machine can't make it)
- No immediate need for plugins - subversion (and Mercurial?) are built in, and since it integrates nicely with ant, I find less need for Ivy etc plugins.
- Multiple classpaths - you have compile time, run time, test compile time and test run-time.  This means if you add something as a test dependency (that your build script knows about), it will not be visible to the main code. Again, very good for IDE / build server consistency.
- Marker navigation is through the task list rather than through the current file.
- Netbeans is *way* slower in updating markers (presumably due to ant compilation rather than eclipse's triple compiler). This causes huge problems when trying to quickly navigate and fix task markers.

Answer (score 1):

The build system is different. Eclipse has an internal build mechanism whilst NetBeans relies on ant.

Answer (score 1):

The popular [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn) productivity tool is a key feature that is only available in Eclipse.

A Joel on Software forum participant wrote: "I've been drawn to Eclipse by a few features, notably: Mylyn, and would like to try it out."
http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.703449

[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn) provides integrated access to your bug and issue tracker. When you work on a bug or issue, Mylyn focuses the Eclipse UI on only the code that is relevant for the task at hand.