# Difference between Eclipse and NetBeans

Tags: java, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Eclipse and Netbeans if I want to use only the Java in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330027/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-and-netbeans-if-i-want-to-use-only-the-jav)

What is the difference between Eclipse and NetBeans IDEs? What are the specific features of both IDEs?

Comment: I'm sorry but is it that hard to do a simple search? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+vs+netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I am a Mac user

Eclipse has a *massive* plugin library and an enormous community behind it.  I've found it to occasionally "pinwheel" when doing large refactors, but other than that it's stable for me.  The JSP editor, has, in the past been somewhat weak for me with regards to properly differentiating between HTML and embedded Java.  I appreciate the extreme configurability of the layout of the different perspectives.  I've never been particularly thrilled with it's editor theming with regards to color schemes.  It's debugger is top-notch.

NetBeans is sort-of the reference platform, you know?  That said, it's plugin library is not as large, though it does have a rather nice vi emulation plugin.  It's always felt slower to me than Eclipse, no matter what I do to it.  It has been known to out-right dump on me as well.  Netbeans has nice integration for different application-deployment platforms, such as Glassfish and Tomcat.