# For Java, which one is more useful Netbeans or Eclipse? 

Tags: java

I am an CS student and have taken only one semester of Java.  I am trying to decide which IDE to choose for Java.  Some people recommend Netbeans and other people say Eclipse.

In the long run, which one is more useful or more practical?  And is there anything else I need to install with it too?

Thanks,
LeoCod

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330027/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-and-netbeans-if-i-want-to-use-only-the-jav

Comment: @org.life.java: Yeah, effectively a dupe of that question.

Comment: Someone's downvoted your question. Please don't take it the wrong way, they haven't allowed for the fact that you're new here. *(Tsk tsk on them.)* **Welcome!** StackOverflow is all about specifics, and so subjective questions ("what's more useful?") are off-topic. Sometimes you can get away with off-topic by making your question a "community wiki" (as with the one linked by org.life.java above; I actually voted to close as a dupe of that, not as subjective). Alternately, check out the equivalent place for subjective programming questions, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. Best,

Comment: *Use the one your teacher recommends!*  This allows you to get the best help possible from your teacher, and IDE's are similar enough that you can pick others up when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is the quasi standard for Java, I would use that.

Comment: Welcome to the world of java.And i will suggest to choose Eclipse ID.
you can download Eclipse from here 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.
Because open source freely available.And near about every type of Plugin you can find.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend eclipse.

1. more people use it
2. It is based on platform that support a lot of plugins. You can always find plugin that helps you to perform certain task.
3. Eclipse is not only a java IDE. there are plugins for other languages. So if you want to develop project utilizing several languages or other projects in other languages you can use the same IDE.

Comment: Point 3 applies for NetBeans as well. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much AlexR.  I just installed Eclipse.  I am going to give a try and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Uuh, I'd say that's a matter of taste in the first place!
Most people would use Eclipse, I think, as Tobiask mentioned already.
I personally prefer NetBeans, because it's more stable in my eyes and ... well, I like it more (matter of taste).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer. I see some people closed my question. I guessed when they started programming they were already genius.