# Which are the standard tools for develop java applications

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Now I am Using Netbeans IDE 7.2 to develop Industrial Applications.

But my friends told me that the applications developing using Netbeans are not standard.

They suggest me eclipse. But I hear that developing applications in eclipse is not easy as in Netbeans.

I want to know which are the industry standard tools for developing java applications.

How could i easily develop standard java industrial applications.

Please help me.

Comment: Use the one you are most comfortable with. Why would industry standard matter here?

Comment: There is no such standard.... Use what you like. Eclipse is much more popular due to lots of integrations, plugins etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are good with one, you will not have any problems with another. Both Netbeans and eclipse are feature rich and freely available.

**Eclipse is the standard IDE for the industry**, may be because it was made by IBM.

**Why I use netbeans**

1. Netbeans comes pre-installed with many plugins
2. Netbeans has a better looking UI than eclipse.
3. You hardly need any configuration with netbeans.

But it is on the heavier side as compared to eclipse. You will find most examples on the web using eclipse, expects demos on oracle's site.

**It depends on what you are developing**.

For example, if you developing a desktop applications. Netbeans comes pre-installed with GUI builder and supports development of java rich internet applcations (javafx, webstart, applet), as it is 
developed by Oracle.

On the other hand, for android development, eclipse is the industrial standard. Since google wants you to use eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact industry standard. Netbeans as fine an IDE as any and it is up to personal taste or goals what you exactly need.

Eclipse a very commonly used IDE, so also a good choice. It's free and has loads of plugins available.

Another option is IntellijIDEA. Downside here is that if you want to use the extra features they build, you will have to buy a license. But there is also a community edition which gets most of the work done, but you will have no Java EE server integration for example.

Als for your question about develop standard java industrial application, any of the above IDE's will do, you just need to try them out which one fits you best. Having specific needs (for example, mobile development, using a specific Java EE server), might narrow the choices, or give you other alternatives (jdeveloper, ibm rational application developer to name a few).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using STS as well, as it is the tool with inbuilt spring perspective

Comment: STS is actually Eclipse on steroids :)

Comment: Yes Silviu correct:) but only inbuild spring perspective

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse or Netbeans, both are "standard" (if that word fits at all in the definition of what is standard). You could even skip them both an use just a plain old text editor. Is just a matter of [personal preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332424/34880).

Answer (score 1):

There is not standard IDE for developing in Java.

Eclipse is one of most used, but there are other IDEs (Netbeans, STS, and so on).

Is a developer choice.

Comment: STS is actually Eclipse on steroids :)