# IDE for Java Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, ide

I'm trying to learn how to build a basic GUI using Java Swing. Right now I know literally nothing about it but I'm going through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html). The first thing I noticed right off the bat was the title: "Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE." Up till now I thought an IDE was basically just something that you could write and run code within (I've been using Eclipse) Why does this tutorial specifically encourage the use of NetBeans?

Edit: And can I just keep using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because Oracle owns/creates NetBeans.

https://netbeans.org/about/history.html

Answer (score 1):

Because Netbeans was acquired by Sun (now Oracle). However I suggest you to use Eclipse, as it has the [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) GUI visual editor, in my opinion the best tool for Java Swing development. The tutorial in the Oracle website however is a good start for a Java Swing novice. Another simple tutorial can be found in [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, NetBeans is owned by the Oracle Corporation and the document you are reading is provided by them as well, therefore it makes sense that the tutorial encourages the use of NetBeans. Yes, you can keep using Eclipse, see the differences/similarities between NetBeans and Eclipse below:

[What is the difference between Eclipse and Netbeans if I want to use only the Java in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330027/what-is-the-difference-between-eclipse-and-netbeans-if-i-want-to-use-only-the-ja)